# How should I compile an angular module package?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package

I'm tying to create my own library in [this repository](https://github.com/rxmoein/rxmoein). When I run `npm run build` the script goes to the `src/components` directory and runs `tsc`. This compiles the code into `js` and `.d.ts` files. But I can't use this package in an angular app.

Why I can not access the components after importing the compiled module? What am I doing wrong?

tsconfig.json in `src/components`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "../../dist/components",
        "declaration": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "types": [],
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2018"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "composite": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you following one of this examples? https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: No I'm trying to create a library like material without bazel

Comment: The guide that Ztemps linked is perfect for that purpose. The default configuration will not use bazel.

Comment: Yes but it's not a good way to create multiple libs in one package like angular material. Anyway it's fixed now, you can take a look at the source code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `tsc` to compile the package but for angular packages the best solution is using `ng-packagr` package.